# MYSQL Find entries that contain more than 7 numbers

Tags: mysql

I need to find entries that contain more than 7 numbers in one of my mysql tables BUT the numbers are separated by letters or anything else.

What I have is this little piece of code I use to find entries like dsc123456789:

```
select * from crawl where title  regexp '[0-9]{7}'
```

How can I find entries like dsc-123-456_78B9? I tried different things but without success so far.

Thanks

Comment: what is your current output

Comment: I think it's hard to solve this if the other characters are totally arbitrary, although some regex guru might be able to do that. Could you specify a full list of characters which can appear between the numbers?

Comment: Characters between the numbers could - _ and A-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT * 
FROM crawl
WHERE title REGEXP '(([^[:digit:]])?[[:digit:]]){8,}';
```

---

**Why the original query of the answer doesn't work?**

```
-- this query doesn't work!
SELECT *  
FROM crawl  
WHERE title REGEXP '\d([^\d]?\d){7,}'
```

MySQL can't use character groups like `\d` (digits). So the query fails every time. On PHP and other languages the regular expression would look like this:

```
\d([^\d]?\d){7,}
```

but on MySQL this isn't valid. So you have to use the [character classes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) of MySQL to solve this:

```
(([^[:digit:]])?[[:digit:]]){8,}
```

> **Hint:** Make sure you use `{8}` or `{8,}` instead of `{7}` since you want to find all entries with more than 7 numbers / digits.

Comment: why it isn't working. add some example data and expected output. Your example (`dsc-123-456_78B9`) above is matching!

Comment: hm if I use this query within my phpmyadmin the result is nothing found. But yes, if I try it with the linked tool, it's working. The example I provided was already part of a existing title.